# How to stop latest Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.5.4) auto formatting files when saving after a minor change to a component on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have an issue where if I do a minor change on Windows Form C# app, the files are automatically formatted on save.

I have tried turning on/off every option that has been suggested when googling, but no joy. The code clean up option, in "Tools->Options->Text Editor->Code Cleanup" seemed the most likely culprit, but turning this off made no difference.

I have tried experimenting to find out when the auto format occurs.
It is when I "Save" the files, but only if I edit a component in the visual form designer. A simple change like changing a button size, causes the whole document to be auto-formatted when I click Save. The formatting includes lots of whitespace changes, as well as removing "this" from all of the component names, etc.
However, if I do the change to the button size manually in the Form1.Designer.cs file (i.e. not using the visual form designer), then only the change to the button size is saved, and the auto formatting does not take place.

Can anyone help.
Tried all the Text Editor formatting options that look likely, plus others suggested when googling. Nothing has worked yet.
Must be a setting somewhere that I have missed, but I can't find it !
Thanks

Comment: The ".Designer.cs" files are NOT intended to be edited directly by the user. They are auto-generated. Use the winforms designer to make changes to the forms/controls.

Comment: Hi Matthew, yes I realise that, but just edited the ".Designer.cs" file manually for comparison of a "Save" of the files. This way does not cause the whole file to be automatically reformatted. However, doing the same change in the winforms designer and then saving does cause the auto reformat. 
The auto reformatting looks reasonable, but I don't want it to happen automatically. It makes diffing files difficult. You see hundreds of whitespace & other formatting changes in the diff when your actual change may have been a simple one line change , e.g. changing the size of a button.

Comment: The code in `.Designer.cs` is not *formatted*, it's rewritten entirely (what's in `InitializeComponent()`) when the Serializer kicks in, to reflect changes made in the visual designer

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for the reply. That makes more sense if the entire file is rewritten as lots of whitespace changes have occurred such as  "this.btnStop.Visible=false;" becomes " this.btnStop.Visible = false;", i.e. spaces have been inserted before and after the equals operator. 
I can't find anyway to stop these whitespace changes automatically happening. Because the file is rewritten like you say, is this something that is just built into the later versions of VS and none of the editor options will alter that ? Certainly seems that way.

Comment: Rewriting the designer's file is not *optional* and it's not related to any recent update of Visual Studio. This is how it has always been. You don't need to care about the `designer.cs` file. Assume it's modified each time you change anything that impacts the visual layout. Or any time it's needed

Comment: Hi Jimi, sorry I wasn't clear in my last comment. What I meant by "built into later versions of VS" was the adding of the extra spaces. Seems that MS have just decided that this is how these files are formatted now. I was used to seeing the designer.cs files in my git diffs with only minimal changes , i.e. the button I had changed size or whatever, but now see lots of whitespace changes throughout the file. 
Anyway, your comments have helped me make sense of it all, and made it clear that I shouldn't worry about the Designer.cs files. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After this "pretty" format on save every thing looks up side down. I didn't find an option in the VS2022 settings to disable it. The only way to avoid format on save is to create an extra file where to keep my source code.

For example if I have Form1.cs, VS2022 create Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.resx. I'm adding one more file Form1src.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
/// Put here your variables and code. 
/// VS2022 don't auto format it after you 
/// change something in Form1.Designer.cs
}
```